# Exactly what equation is solved by python fluidsim (object oriented CDF solver)

Tags: python, equation, fluid, fluid-dynamics

I have a question about the fluidsim python package. I would like to use the fluidsim program for my research. After reading the documentation, it is not clear what equation exactly the fluidsim.solvers.ns2d.solver algorithm solves (I would be interested in the specific form of the differential equation), and it is also a question of how to add new equations to the existing ones. If any of you know exactly what equation solves fluidsim.solvers.ns2d.solver or how to add a new equation to your existing equations please write to me. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, it solves the 2D Navier-Stokes equations:

> This module provides two classes defining the pseudo-spectral solver 2D incompressible Navier-Stokes equations (ns2d).

[Source](https://fluidsim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/fluidsim.solvers.ns2d.solver.html?highlight=ns2d.solver)

To define your own equations, have a look at how they are defined in the library: https://fluidsim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ipynb/tuto_dev.html?highlight=define%20equations#description-of-the-solved-equations